# Is there any target on Automake that is executed before the automake Makefile rules?

Tags: hook, automake

I've been trying to generate Makefile rules that execute *before* the
automake Makefile rules. I've seen I can define "all-local" and "hooks" rules, but these are executed *after* the "all" and other
rules, for instance.

Is there any way that I could execute a code of mine before the
automake added rules? I want to automatically generate files in a
directory, but the compilation process through make always tries to
compile programs following automake Makefile rules. If I could add a
"pre-" rule, I could generate the needed files, then let the normal
compilation process to run.

I know about BUILT_SOURCES, but I'm trying not to use it

Is that possible?
Thanks!

Comment: That's what `BUILT_SOURCES` is for - why on earth are you trying not to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this.

In general in a Makefile, if you want to do this, you should instead consider adding proper dependencies where needed.

Comment: This is not true: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67946829/186347) for a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles can have the same target with different prerequisites, in which case the prerequisites will be merged:

```
# The following will be equivalent to 'target: prerequisite1 prerequisite2'
target: prerequisite1
target: prerequisite2
```

This can be inferred from [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html) (really bad explanation there, but I did not find anything better).

You can leverage this feature in your own `Makefile.am`:

```
all: all-prehook

all-prehook:
    echo Prehook called here

.PHONY: all-prehook
```

Be careful automake will complain (`Warning: overrides Automake target` or something similar). You could shut it up by using `-Wno-override`: if your are using autoconf, just add it to your `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` call.