# Tell automake to run a few commands on a program just before installing or just after linking

Tags: automake

I would like use automake to process/modify the binaries before they are installed. For example, I would like to extract the symbols from the binary into a separate file and location (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866721/how-to-generate-gcc-debug-symbol-outside-the-build-target)). Another example is to collect the md5sums of critical assets for publishing a report.

This is a simplified (but representative) Makefile.am that I have:

```
abc_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.cpp

pqr_PROGRAMS = bar
bar_SOURCES = bar.cpp

ALL_SYMS := $(PROGRAMS:%=%.sym)

sym_DATA = $(ALL_SYMS)

# A convenient target such as "make foo.sym" will trigger this rule:
$(ALL_SYMS): %.sym : %
   ...
   objcopy --preserve-dates --only-keep-debug $< $@
   objcopy --preserve-dates --strip-all --add-gnu-debuglink=$@ $<
   ...
```

I have tried a few ways to hook in my script in during install, but with limited success.

1. One potential way is using install-exec-local:

   ```
   install-exec-local: $(ALL_SYMS)
   ```

   The problem with install-exec-local is that when I use: "make install -j", the
   install-exec-local target runs in parallel with the install, so binaries foo and bar
   get installed into at their respective destination dirs, even while they are being
   were being modified by the %.sym rule, thereby potentiall messing up the installed
   files. However this solution works if -j is not used. I would like if I can leverage
   the advantages of using -j.
2. Another potential way is using install-exec-hook:

   ```
   install-exec-hook: $(ALL_SYMS)
   ```

   The problem with install-exec-hook is that the programs foo and bar are already
   installed before I get a chance to modify them using the %.sym rule. Besides foo
   and bar get installed at different locations, I don't have a generic way to
   get their destination locations while writing a suitable install-exec-hook rule.
3. Another potential way is to define STRIP_PROGRAM or something equivalent, but that
   does not work really well, because i think it won't work with the "make install"
   target, but only with "make install-strip -j". I have not gone this path, because our
   build scripts use "make install -j".
4. Another way is to do it is by creating build rules that run during build time rather
   than install time. But this one is really cumbersome, that it creates many files in
   the build directory and I would like to avoid it. Also new people in the project while
   adding new programs can easily bypass these finely tuned elaborate arrangements.

   ```
   abc_PROGRAMS = foo
   foo : foo.tmp
   foo.sym : foo
   noinst_PROGRAMS = foo.tmp
   foo_tmp_SOURCES = foo.cpp


   pqr_PROGRAMS = bar
   bar : bar.tmp
   bar.sym : bar
   noinst_PROGRAMS += bar.tmp
   bar_tmp_SOURCES = bar.cpp

   sym_DATA = foo.sym bar.sym

   foo bar: % : %.tmp
   ...
   cp $@ $<
   objcopy --only-keep-debug $@ $@.sym
   objcopy --strip-all --add-gnu-debuglink=$@.sym $@
   ```

I would have loved if automake provided a hook which ran before a program is installed, or just after a program is built.

The stackoverflow.com community is really making a difference to the quality of solutions that are available on the internet. I am sure someone must have faced a problem similar to mine. I am awaiting good solutions or industry best practices on this issue. Lastly, I apologize for not being able to make the question much more brief or easier to understand.

Comment: Also see [Post build step and Makefile.am](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2006-01/msg00144.html) on the Automake mailing list.

Comment: For a way to execute you code **before** automake, you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67946829/186347) to another thread.

Answer (score 3):

> Tell automake to run a few commands on a program just before installing or just after linking

The "just after linking" part can be accomplished using `libtool`'s `postlink_cmds` step. [`postlink_cmds` is documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/libtool-script-contents.html#index-postlink_005fcmds):

> ***Variable: postlink_cmds***
>
> Commands necessary for finishing linking programs. postlink_cmds are executed immediately after the program is linked. Any occurrence of the string @OUTPUT@ in postlink_cmds is replaced by the name of the created executable (i.e. not the wrapper, if a wrapper is generated) prior to execution. Similarly, @TOOL_OUTPUT@ is replaced by the toolchain format of @OUTPUT@. Normally disabled (i.e. postlink_cmds empty).

---

Below is part of a `configure.ac` that uses `sed` to patch `libtool` and `postlink_cmds` after `libtool` is created. We needed it to apply software capabilities on a Solaris shared object because our link options to set them through a mapfile `-M <mapfile>` was being stripped (apparently [`libtool` reserves nearly all `-M` options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205778/608639)).

Though `libtool` has a `postlink_cmds` we don't know how to set it more traditionally. Maybe there is a `AC_XXX` somewhere to do it.

```
#############################################################################
## Hack ahead. GNU's libtool does not honor our '-M cryptopp.mapfile' in AM_LDFLAGS
## for the libcryptopp.so recipe. Many thanks to John Martin of Oracle for help wielding
## elfedit. The hw_cap = 0x1800 is SSE2 SSE and its needed for old hardware when new
## instructions are present, like SSE4.1, SSE4.2, CLMUL, AES, RDRAND, RDSEED and SHA.
## TODO: determine if we are allowed to hijack libtool's postlink_cmds function. It
## works well but we may be violating a policy somewhere along the line.

if test "$IS_SUN_OS" -ne "0" && test "$IS_SUN_COMPILER" -ne "0"; then
   if test "$IS_IA32" -ne "0"; then

      echo "Adding postlink script"
      rm -f postlink.sh 2>/dev/null
      echo "echo \"Fixing shared object capabilities\"" >> postlink.sh
      echo "elfedit -e 'cap:hw1 0x1800' .libs/cryptest" >> postlink.sh
      echo "elfedit -e 'cap:hw1 0x1800' .libs/cryptestcwd" >> postlink.sh
      echo "elfedit -e 'cap:hw1 0x1800' .libs/libcryptopp.so.6.0.0" >> postlink.sh
      echo "" >> postlink.sh
      chmod +x postlink.sh

      echo "Adding postlink script to libtool postlink_cmds"
      sed 's|postlink_cmds=""|postlink_cmds="./postlink.sh"|g' libtool > libtool.fixed
      mv libtool.fixed libtool
      chmod +x libtool
   fi
fi
```

---

Before hacking with `sed`, I tried setting `postlink_cmds` more traditionally in `configure.ac`. Unfortunately, it did not work and it resulted in `postlink_cmds=""` in the generated `libtool`. Here is something that *does not* work:

```
if test x"$postlink_cmds" = "x"; then
    postlink_cmds="./postlink.sh"
else
    postlink_cmds="~ ./postlink.sh"
fi
```

The `~` is due to the [`libtool` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/libtool-script-contents.html#index-postlink_005fcmds) stating:

> ... The convention used for naming variables that hold shell commands for delayed evaluation, is to use the suffix _cmd where a single line of valid shell script is needed, and the suffix _cmds where multiple lines of shell script may be delayed for later evaluation. By convention, _cmds variables delimit the evaluation units with the ~ character where necessary.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same issue with "postlink_cmds" being ignored in configure.ac. The solution is to set "postlink_cmds" and "postlink_cmds_CXX" (CXX might be different for C projects, didn't check this further) to the same commands.

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of option #3, you might in this case consider setting up one of the `INSTALL` variables (INSTALL, INSTALL_DATA, INSTALL_PROGRAM, INSTALL_SCRIPT) and point it at a script that does what you want, and calls the real `install` as the last step.

Comment: Is there any way to do it after successful build? I need to fix a shared object on Solaris that has wrong capabilities before trying to run my self tests. Otherwise, this is the result: [Mapfile missing from shared object artifact?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2017-11/msg00021.html).